# Layout problems while launching my app

Tags: java, android

I have a problem when I run my app: the Button is not where it should be.
Does anyone know why?

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Text Window from that xml you should see a red underline on the Button, that is because`"This view is not constrained"`.
So, go to Design window and constraint the button clicking the "handles" (small circles).
Official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using ConstraintLayout, but you don't have any constraints on the view. Meaning it jumps to (0, 0) when you run the app.

Add constraints to the view, or it jumps to (0, 0)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any constrains, because of that the view will automatically move to the top left by default. Add constrains left/right and top to parent. You can use margin to offset the view from the top